# requirejs works incorrect with cache when loaded from callback function

Tags: requirejs

My javascript resource request (**/myscript.js**) contains the following in response headers.

```
Cache-Control   must-revalidate
Content-Length  15
Content-Type    text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 14 Oct 2014 11:32:01 GMT
Expires Mon, 14 Oct 2024 10:54:04 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 14 Oct 2004 10:54:04 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I set Expires to the date that is located in deep future so I expect that any further requests to **/myscript.js** should be taken from browser cache.

I request **/myscript.js** using requirejs:

```
require([('/myscript.js']);
```

I also note that all cache manipulations (F5 and Ctrl+F5) work properly with this.

F5 causes **If-Modified-Since** request.

Ctrl+F5 clears cache and reloads script.

But if I place that code into some callback (like jquery ready or setTimeout):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    require([('/myscript.js']);
});
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
    require([('/myscript.js']);
},1);
```

everything goes wrong. Even Ctrl+F5 doesn't clear cache and this script is taken from cache.

In Network panel of my browser I see the following

Firefox (F5)
[image: Firefox]

Firefox (Ctrl + F5)
[image]

Chrome (F5)
[image]

Chrome (Ctrl + F5)
[image]

Please, explain, why Ctrl+F5 doesn't clear the cache in this situation?

Comment: Since when and how the cache is cleared is browser-dependent behavior, you need to indicate which browser you are using. Also, please show your evidence that in one case the cache *is* used and in the other case *is not* used.

Comment: Added screenshots to the question, for Firefox and Chrome.